# Choosing possible highest number

Tags: java, arrays, random

i'm doing Card game with java and there is one simple rule you have to choose number equal to previous or lower. I can't make program to choose equal or lower number than previous.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random First = new Random();
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
        System.out.print("First card is: ");
        int FirstCard = 8;
        int Losowa = First.nextInt(FirstCard);
        System.out.println(Losowa);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(600);
        Random il_kart = new Random();
        System.out.print("Your cards: ");
        for (int i = tablica[0]; i < 5; i++) {
            int upperbound = 8;
            tablica[i] = il_kart.nextInt(upperbound);
            System.out.print(tablica[i] + " ");
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(250);


        }


        Random Enemy_cards = new Random();
        System.out.print("enemy's card is: ");
        for (int i = EnemyTab[0]; i < 5; i++) {
            int upperbound = 8;
            EnemyTab[i] = il_kart.nextInt(upperbound);
            System.out.print(EnemyTab[i] + " ");
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(250);
        }
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(800);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Your turn!");

        if (tablica[0] <= Losowa || tablica[1] <= Losowa || tablica[2] <= Losowa || tablica[3] <= Losowa || tablica[4] <= Losowa) {

            Scanner choose = new Scanner(System.in);
            int wyb = choose.nextInt();
            if (wyb <= tablica[0] || wyb <= tablica[1] || wyb <= tablica[2] || wyb <= tablica[3] || wyb <= tablica[4]) {
                System.out.println("You choose " + wyb);
            }
            while (wyb > Losowa) {
                System.out.print("You can't play this");
                System.out.println("Choose another card");
                choose = new Scanner(System.in);
                wyb = choose.nextInt();
                System.out.println("You choose " + wyb);
            }

        } else if (tablica[0] != Losowa || tablica[1] != Losowa || tablica[2] != Losowa || tablica[3] != Losowa || tablica[4] != Losowa) {
            System.out.println("You can't play any card");
        }

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(800);
        System.out.println("Enemy's turn...");
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(800);
        System.out.print("Your opponent plays: ");

        if (EnemyTab[0] <= Losowa || EnemyTab[0] <= tablica[wyb] || EnemyTab[1] <= Losowa || EnemyTab[1] <= tablica[wyb] || EnemyTab[2] <= Losowa || EnemyTab[2] <= tablica[wyb] || EnemyTab[3] <= Losowa || EnemyTab[3] <= tablica[wyb] || EnemyTab[4] <= Losowa || EnemyTab[4] <= tablica[wyb]) {
            int odp = tablica[wyb];
            for (int i = 0; i <= EnemyTab.length; i++)
                System.out.println(odp);

            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(800);




        }
```

The output is:

```
First card: 5
Your cards are: 1 4 7 0 4  
enemy's card is: 6 7 6 6 3  
Your turn!
4
You choose: 4
Enemy's turn...
Your enemy plays: 7
7
7
7
7
7
Round 2
Your turn!
```

What can i do to make computer choose number equal to mine or lower? Losowa is first random card, wyb is Scanner (choosing card)

Comment: Think about rewriting your code in a way that you don't have so many conditions in your ```if``` statement.

Comment: can you describe the logic behind your if statement (also explaining/translating what Losowa, tablica, wyb, and odp contain/mean)? Can you post a bigger part of your code, to help us understand how those prints are generated? To get you started, one simple solution would be : for every card in the enemyTab, if it is less than or equal to the current card, print it (and break the loop maybe). The more you help us understand the problem, the more we can help you :)

Comment: Losowa is First Random card, Tablica is array with random cards, wyb is Scanner (choosing Card), odp is answer. I tried using if statemant in many ways, the problem is sometimes the program chooses right answer but mostly it chooses higher card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, is to construct an ArrayList named equalOrLower let's say, and whenever it is computers time to choose, a new ArrayList is created, which will store all the enemy possible cards whose value is less than the players number. The enemy (computer) can then only choose a value from the newly created ArrayList.

```
 int playerNumber = 5;
    int[] enemyPossibleCards = {1,2,6,4,9};

    ArrayList<Integer> equalOrLess = new ArrayList<>();

    equalOrLess.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < enemyPossibleCards.length; i++){
        if(enemyPossibleCards[i] < playerNumber)
            equalOrLess.add(enemyPossibleCards[i]);
    }
```

This is some example code to help you understand my answer. The ArrayList will be cleared every time the function is called in order to make sure the previous values are deleted. Please reach out if you have any further questions :)

Comment: Thank you :) I will try it tommorow.